# Remove XML hierarchy elements with the same name using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

An **XML** response I am getting has the same named elements next to each other in the response which is causing me issues, I need to remove this recurring element using **XSLT 1.0**. The element in question in the response is `<RoundIncidents>` . I have had a look through other questions but can't find what I need to transform the response to the correct format.

### XML Response with Recurring Element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetSiteIncidentsResponse xmlns="http://webservices.whitespacews.com/">
         <GetSiteIncidentsResult>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDescription>Success</ErrorDescription>
            <SuccessFlag>true</SuccessFlag>
            <RoundIncidents>
               <RoundIncidents>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <AccountSiteID>0</AccountSiteID>
                  <RoundIncidentID>8</RoundIncidentID>
                  <RoundRoundAreaServiceScheduleID>157</RoundRoundAreaServiceScheduleID>
                  <RoundCode>REC1</RoundCode>
                  <ScheduleName>MonFort2</ScheduleName>
                  <ServiceName>Recycling Collection Service</ServiceName>
                  <RoundAreaName>REC1 - MonFort2</RoundAreaName>
                  <RoundIncidentDate>2019-04-08T16:12:10</RoundIncidentDate>
                  <RoundIncidentNotes>Road Closed</RoundIncidentNotes>
                  <RoundIncidentCreatedByID>129</RoundIncidentCreatedByID>
                  <RoundIncidentCreatedDate>2019-04-08T16:12:26.493</RoundIncidentCreatedDate>
               </RoundIncidents>
            </RoundIncidents>
         </GetSiteIncidentsResult>
      </GetSiteIncidentsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

### Desired Outcome following XSLT Transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetSiteIncidentsResponse xmlns="http://webservices.whitespacews.com/">
         <GetSiteIncidentsResult>
            <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDescription>Success</ErrorDescription>
            <SuccessFlag>true</SuccessFlag>            
               <RoundIncidents>
                  <ExtensionData />
                  <AccountSiteID>0</AccountSiteID>
                  <RoundIncidentID>8</RoundIncidentID>
                  <RoundRoundAreaServiceScheduleID>157</RoundRoundAreaServiceScheduleID>
                  <RoundCode>REC1</RoundCode>
                  <ScheduleName>MonFort2</ScheduleName>
                  <ServiceName>Recycling Collection Service</ServiceName>
                  <RoundAreaName>REC1 - MonFort2</RoundAreaName>
                  <RoundIncidentDate>2019-04-08T16:12:10</RoundIncidentDate>
                  <RoundIncidentNotes>Road Closed</RoundIncidentNotes>
                  <RoundIncidentCreatedByID>129</RoundIncidentCreatedByID>
                  <RoundIncidentCreatedDate>2019-04-08T16:12:26.493</RoundIncidentCreatedDate>
               </RoundIncidents>            
         </GetSiteIncidentsResult>
      </GetSiteIncidentsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Removing Child

Add a template to the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) that matches child elements where
the parent and child have the same [QName](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-QName), and the child is bypassed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[name() = name(..)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mw/2) on Martin Honnen's handy XSLT Fiddle.

Note that the above *lexically* compares QNames, which may include namespace prefixes.  To compare names properly (*semantically*), check the namespace URIs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[    local-name() = local-name(..) 
                         and namespace-uri() = namespace-uri(..)]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Updated [demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mw/3).

---

### Removing Parent

Per OP's updated request, here's how to remove the parent element when there's a child element named the same.  In choosing which approach to take, consider that in general a child can only have one parent, but a parent can have multiple children.

Simple QName [check](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mw/4):

```
<xsl:template match="*[*[name() = name(..)]]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Full Namespace URI [check](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncdD7mw/5):

```
<xsl:template match="*[*[    local-name() = local-name(..) 
                         and namespace-uri() = namespace-uri(..)]]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Credit:** Thanks to [@Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11102282/alejandro) and [@michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k) for helpful corrections and improvements.

Comment: That pattern match an element with the same QName as the parent. Besides the problem of comparing namespace prefixes and not namespaces URIs, the correct sentence should be that this **match and bypass the childs** (and posible grandchilds because it's a relative pattern) **copying the parent** (wich it's a good approach, imho).

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for the improvement suggestions.  Answer updated.

Comment: The question is tagged as XSLT 1.0 but the answer requires XSLT 2.0. For XSLT 1.0 you need to use `<xsl:template match="*[name()=name(..)]">`  or - to answer the concern raised by Alejandro: `<xsl:template match="*[local-name()=local-name(..) and namespace-uri()=namespace-uri(..)]">`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k:  Agreed.  Answer updated.  Thank you!

Comment: I have realised that from my above example of desired outcome I didn't specify which <RoundIncidents> element I wanted removing and the solutions remove the child element, I need an solution so the parent <RoundIncidents> element under the <GetSiteIncidentsResult> element is removed from the XML tree

Comment: @JSTIRLS:  Ok, answer updated to show how to remove a parent element named the same as the child.

Comment: @JSTIRLS Do you really need a generic solution for this? To get the result in your example, you could simply do `<xsl:template match="soap:Body/ns1:GetSiteIncidentsResponse">` (with the corresponding namespace declarations).

Comment: @michael.hor257k The above solution worked for me as a generic solution is what I wanted as I am using lots of different API look ups and the XML responses all differ but all have the same issue with recurring parent child elements with the same name which the CRM system I am using cannot resolve. Using one generic style sheet I am able to remove this element and extract various pieces of data from the responses as required.

Comment: It has been good to see all the different options available and as I am new to XSLT this has been very useful, thank you.